# Impute missing observations R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of Calendar days and Hourly observations with associated values like so:

```
   startTime  Hour  delay
   04-22      0     10
   04-22      1     10
   04-22      3     10
   04-22      4     10
```

What's needed is all hours of the day and a 0 associated with said missing hours instead of no value or an NA. How would this best be achieved? I have attempted full_join from dplyr with a dummy data frame, but this method seems clunky and inefficient.

In short, I need this:

```
   startTime  Hour  delay
   04-22      0     10
   04-22      1     10
   04-22      2     0
   04-22      3     10
   04-22      4     10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `data.table` to efficiently join the dataset.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table`(`setDT(df1)`), set the key columns (`setkey(.., startTime, Hour)`), join with the combination of unique values of 'startTime' and 'Hour', and replace the NA values in delay with '0'

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1), startTime, Hour)[CJ(startTime=unique(startTime), 
     Hour=min(Hour):max(Hour))][is.na(delay), delay:=0L]
#   startTime Hour delay
#1:     04-22    0    10
#2:     04-22    1    10
#3:     04-22    2     0
#4:     04-22    3    10
#5:     04-22    4    10
```

Or using `merge/expand.grid` from `base R`, we can get the above result

```
merge(expand.grid(startTime=unique(df1$startTime),
      Hour= min(df1$Hour):max(df1$Hour)), df1, all.x=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using dplyr and zoo:

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo) #na.locf

#dummy data
df1 <- read.table(text="   startTime  Hour  delay
   04-22      0     10
                  04-22      1     10
                  04-22      3     10
                  04-22      4     10",header=TRUE)

#result
full_join(df1,data.frame(Hour=0:23),
          by="Hour") %>% 
  arrange(Hour,startTime) %>% 
  mutate(startTime=na.locf(startTime),
         delay=ifelse(is.na(delay),0,delay))
```